# How can I plot y=mx+b in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

I was wondering if it is possible to plot a line of the form `y = mx+b` in Matlab? I used `polyfit` to get a 1x2 array that contains the slope and intercept.

Here is what I have so far:

```
lineFit = polyfit(tauBin, a5array, 1);
plot((lineFit(1)*x + lineFit(2)))
```

How can I plot this?

Comment: are you asking how to fit a line to experimental/observation data, or how to plot an array of values?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two way that immediately come to mind. The first is with [FPLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fplot.html):

```
>> m = 2; b = 1;
>> fplot(@(x)m*x+b, [0 10]);
```

The second is to calculate the y values directly in the call to the [PLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) command:

```
>> m = 2; b = 1; x = 1:10;
>> plot(x, m*x+b);
```

Comment: Thank you so much b3! I wound up using this, it worked like a charm: `figure plot(tauBin, a5array, '.-r') hold on xLimMin = min(tauBin)-10; xLimMax = max(tauBin)+10; xlim([xLimMin xLimMax]) xRange = xLimMin:xLimMax lineFit = polyfit(tauBin, a5array, 1); lineFitx = a5array(1:length(a5array)); plot(xRange, lineFit(1)*xRange+lineFit(2), '-b');`

Comment: @Alex Nichols - Glad to help. If you haven't already, you may wish to read up on anonymous functions (like the one used in the fplot example above). They crop up all over the place and should be a tool in your arsenal.

Comment: For reasons of optimization and to avoid problems with `xLimMax-xLimMin < 1` you should set `xRange = [xLimMin,xLimMax]`.

Answer (score 4):

There is [REFLINE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/refline.html) function in Statistical Toolbox. Probably the easiest for your task:

```
refline(m,b)
```

or if you want to change line properties:

```
hr = refline(m,b);
set(hr,'Color','r')
```

It uses limits from the current axes. So if you change the limits later, it probably would be easier to delete it (`delete(hr)`) and draw again.

Comment: I wish that `refline` can take inputs to modify line properties like color. But sadly, it doesn't.

Comment: @Sam, you can easily add this feature to the refline function. Make a copy, change name to like myrefline. Change the definition to `function h = myrefline(slope,intercept,varargin)`. Then in the body `set(hh,varargin{:});`. This should work then: `myrefline(1,0,'Color','b','LineStyle',':')`.